# Unexpected End-of-file (1AH) in .dbf file

Tags: python-3.x, dbf

I am using the excellent [`dbf` package for Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf/0.96.003) to read data from a .dbf file. The file is produced by a proprietary Windows application whose source code I cannot access. `dbf` says the .dbf is a `Foxpro` file.

The .dbf file is continually updated, so I re-read it regularly. It contains over a million records. Everything was fine until today, when I suddenly received the following error:

```
DbfError: record data not correct -- first character should be a ' ' or a '*'.
```

Closer inspection reveals that the data for the corresponding record (#46448) now starts with ASCII character `26` (`0x1A`). [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dbf) says that this character is used in .dbf files as an end-of-file marker. Why does this character appear in the middle of the file all of a sudden?

There is also a [forum post](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1617402) by someone who seems to have had the same problem. Unfortunately, no resolution is given there.

Comment: What is the physical size of the file? How large is each record?  Can you share the file with me? (I can sign an NDA if necessary.)  And I'm glad you find dbf useful!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the creating application.  Further digging showed there was only one record with `0x1A` in that field, and that application was treating the record normally.